# Center child ConstraintLayout vertically in parent

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a layout with a child `ContraintLayout` group that is centered vertically in a parent ConstraintLayout which also allows for the child to increase its size vertically if it needs to
if there is a lot of text.

This is what I have with it centered how I want but when using the

```
app:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/social_media_auto_text_sizes"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

of a TextView (android:id="@+id/message" I am concerned about here) the view height does not increase so its cuts off text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contentImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/contentImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/social_media_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:text="Sample text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/social_media_auto_text_sizes"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/username"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I change the child ConstraintLayout height to `android:layout_height="0dp"` along with the TextView height to `android:layout_height="0dp"` I get the text to scale like I want but now all the stuff in the child is not centered like I want it.

Layout with above changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contentImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/contentImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/social_media_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:text="Sample text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/social_media_auto_text_sizes"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/username"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

what do I need to adjust so I can have the constraint layout that holds the `message` TextView to be centered and increase its height when there is more text with the `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#setting-textview-autosize):

> **Note**: If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the value "wrap_content" for the `layout_width` or `layout_height` attributes of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results.

If you can't set a fixed height to the *TextView*, you should be able to specify *match_constraints* for the maximum size and make adjustments programmatically depending upon your exact requirements.

Comment: even settings the TextView height to match_parent or setting the end constraint to the end of the parent didn't do it though

Comment: @tyczj So, you want a _TextView_ that will expand to wrap its content at the largest autosize text size where all the text will fit. Text will only be cut off if the smallest autosize text size can't fit. Is that right?

Comment: @tyczj I think that you will need a custom view similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50696258/6287910).